# Как сделать перекрестный join 2х колонок одного поля в 1 таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Есть таблица соответствия друзей

```
--------------------------------
idUser | IdfriendUser | DateAdd |
--------------------------------
1      | 2            | date    |
---------------------------------
2      | 3            | date    |
---------------------------------
```

как получить таблицу которая продублирует поле друга в поле юзера и поле юзера в поле друга

```
------------------------------------
idUser | IdfriendUser | DateAdd |
------------------------------------
1      | 2            | date    |
------------------------------------
2      | 1            | date    |
------------------------------------
2      | 3            | date    |
------------------------------------
3      | 2            | date    |
------------------------------------
```

и стоит ли вообще это делать таким образом?

Comment: `select A, B from table union select B,A from table`. А стоит ли это делать или нет - решать только вам, все зависит от задачи для которой вам понадобилась такая выборка

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    idUser, 
    IdfriendUser, 
    DateAdd  
from 
    table
union select 
    IdfriendUser, 
    idUser, 
    DateAdd  
from 
    table
```